# Cakephp: Login function doesn't work on client server

Tags: cakephp, authentication

The login function can work on local server and uni server, but it doesn't work on the client's server.

checked the salt, the same as local core.php 
checked the password, char(40),
set debug to 2,
deleting the cache files from the app/tmp/cache folder and subfolders,

but nothing happened, I still can not login the system.

I am not sure where I should be looking next, I am very confused.

client server
PHP version:5.3.17
CakePHP: 2.2.3

Many Thanks.

Comment: in login page, there is no error, just doesn't redirect the page to the dashboard or error message. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the user database is in the same format and has the same data?

Comment: Did you check the DB to ensure the user is actually in the Database? If it is, then create a new user and Copy-Paste this user's hashed password into the password field of the user you are trying to log in with.

Comment: Yes, I check the password, it stores as Hashed, same as local DB

Comment: I input username and hashed password, the same result, the auth doesn't work. Please help me, give me some advice, any help are appreciated.....

Comment: I add an new account, it stored to DB, but cannot login

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
Remove all the white space after the end of } tag in controllers and models.
Now, it works.

The reason(found in Google Search):
' the issue is a PHP issue with whitespace being output after some headers are sent, and typically occurs when a redirect is requested further down in the code from the whitespace. This issue has nothing to do specifically with CakePHP as implied in the post title.'

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

I got the SAME problem. removed all the white space after the end tag in PHP in ALL .php and .CTP files. over 1000 of them.

I believe it is something to do with folder permissions because in localhost it works FINE and Dandy and in my case I know the server has a lot of permission issues.

---